# Imbalanced data in h2o

Tags: h2o

I am running glm model in H2o with highly imbalanced binary response variable, my problem is that when setting the argument balance_classes True, it doesn't work and I get the same result as false. Thanks

Comment: What is the class imbalance? e.g. 1:10, 1:100, 1:1000?

Comment: Are you getting the exact same result, or just a very similar result?

Comment: I got exactly the same result, the data is creditcard,  highly imbalanced with 0.1% for the minor

Answer (score 0):

Although the argument `balance_classes` is available in H2O GLM, the algorithm itself does not require special handling for imbalanced data. Not sure if it applies in general, but it seems it applies in H2O. You may refer to the FAQ section, [How does the algorithm handle highly imbalanced data in a response column?](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glm.html#faq), to verify it.